# Can you combine Strip and Paddle in a single Laravel Spark application?

Tags: laravel-spark

I already have an existing Laravel Spark site running that employs the Stripe payment provider. I noticed that the newest Laravel Spark supports PayPal using the Paddle payment provider. On the [spark website](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.x/introduction.html), it says:

> **Supported Payment Providers**
> Spark supports two payment providers, and purchasing a Spark license grants you the ability to use either of these payment providers.

I guess it's therefore not possible to combine both providers and have a single site that allows users to use Stripe or Paddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box it's not possible to use both payment providers. Once a provider is selected [during the installation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.x/installation.html#installing-spark-via-composer) of Spark, you'll end up with either the `laravel/spark-paddle` composer package or the `laravel/spark-stripe` package.

It's probably possible to hack Spark to support both providers, but there will be a bunch of conflicts to work around. For example, the two packages will have conflicting migrations.

It would be much easier to create a custom solution.